# Scaling dual y axis plot in R using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, scaling

I am trying to create a depth and temperature vs time plot. The temperature ranged from 14-21C and the depth ranged from 0-7.5m. I am having issues forcing the temperature scale to only be from 14-21 while the depth scale remains at 0-7.5. I am also having problems figuring out how only to reverse the primary axis and keep the secondary axis unreversed.

This picture is what I have so far [image: the plot i currenlty can make]

however, i need the secondary scale expanded and the scale of it to be un reversed.

Here is the code I am working with/currently:

```
coeff <- 3.5

ggplot(dat, aes(x = hour)) +
geom_line(aes(y = avg_depth), color = "black") +
geom_line(aes(y = (avg_temp / coeff)), color = "red") +
scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse", name = "depth m", breaks = seq(0,7.5,1), sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*coeff, name = "temp c", breaks = seq(14,22,1))) +
theme_bw() +
theme( axis.title.y = element_text(color = "black", size=13), axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "red", size=13) ) +
facet_wrap(~month)
```

Here is a dput() output of what the data look like

```
dat <- structure(list(hour = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L,  14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L), month = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,  5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L,  3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"), class = "factor"), avg_depth = c(0.674104255319149, 1.16141723716381, 0.46781443148688, 0.569350711610487, 0.821086666666667, 1.85221716906946, 3.4268076419214, 5.65440574712644, 0.616312741312741, 1.47207503201024, 0.616066710182768,  0.638740190972222, 0.810777301790281, 2.01457261676264, 3.36415133437991, 6.15696138613861, 0.610769090909091, 1.27732580152672, 0.4530571197411, 0.693855674102813, 0.952273323285607, 1.74055824706694, 3.61179272727273, 5.98195405405405, 0.722235111111111, 1.52565404580153, 0.379650976909414, 0.587217663817664, 0.863865517241379, 1.60190743289745, 3.98509323671498, 7.17103939393939, 1.16354933333333, 1.63964759124088, 0.22209219269103, 0.608081025641026, 0.928734545454545, 1.83999729136164, 3.74237966101695,  5.117916, 2.8523356223176, 3.11033643533123, 1.75334429530201, 1.12571253588517, 1.12463694805195, 1.97661355585831, 4.84568290258449, 4.76447142857143, 2.11757875, 2.40585516483516, 1.09251965517241, 1.60237222222222, 1.83568177710843, 2.75534613702624, 4.04060363128492, 5.78596666666667, 2.63774363636364, 2.29331220930233, 0.77616, 1.10007866184448, 1.42876923076923, 2.01189947368421, 3.84362485714286, 6.71578, 2.13474590163934, 2.17037283018868, 0.694685217391304, 1.43871231060606, 1.32960293308891,  2.01551460423634, 3.34886953488372, 5.59423725490196, 2.29458939393939, 1.92593313432836, 0.441394570135747, 1.14764970588235, 1.39075131164743, 1.69570840707965, 2.38680161290323, 5.72604857142857, 1.24143787878788, 1.71293395061728, 0.408103184713376, 0.694587361111111, 1.16296766169154, 1.42053806881243, 2.05217391304348, 4.45380344827586, 1.44979530201342, 1.30386650246305, 0.276496173469388, 0.409692631578947, 0.796362308478039, 1.40612004175365, 1.63052086614173, 4.69366923076923, 1.42541492537313,  1.26328473282443, 0.53241756097561, 0.441229568788501, 0.737582608695652, 1.1452046692607, 1.79292577903683, 4.49204736842105, 0.91743063583815, 0.831260960960961, 0.503330205949657, 0.26842350877193, 0.644189047619048, 0.910615674255692, 1.22900170731707, 3.54798510638298, 0.571305025125628, 0.129495254237288, 0.206634959349593, 0.21165325, 0.536572630560928, 0.667085635359116, 1.16518847184987, 3.58613655913978, 0.910796721311475, 0.867520072992701, 0.188670698924731, 0.135299527744982, 0.611749167591565,  0.755583778801843, 1.79804401294498, 4.17658985507246, 0.638515668202765, 0.995278481012658, 0.163949529780564, 0.197539821693908, 0.698209720372836, 0.784387046004843, 2.32800274390244, 3.81578292682927, 1.108674, 1.15969727272727, 0.300007692307692, 0.55911566091954, 0.831757255936675, 1.22999745508982, 2.41673333333333, 4.97039180327869, 1.71473367346939, 1.34693986486486, 0.263691570881226, 0.438736363636364, 1.11891881067961, 2.59670830860534, 3.96090025575448, 4.2819350877193, 1.73873260869565,  2.79971208459214, 0.643953846153846, 1.02863309957924, 1.64601155234657, 2.34617211191336, 4.22193452914798, 3.41848, 2.95643957446809, 3.77135458823529, 0.664984664536741, 1.58177615298088, 0.927709062253743, 2.04243081761006, 4.00474120603015, 5.08179565217391, 0.964061157024793, 1.67683, 0.691920124481328, 0.492731824817518, 1.25362104909213, 2.05283324538259, 4.03329810126582, 4.84152526315789, 0.669290188679245, 0.882096637744035, 0.67114227886057, 0.507457641311933, 1.09130144665461, 2.14580438709677,  4.08386100217865, 5.09187647058824, 0.725805681818182, 1.00826231038506, 0.403857034795764, 0.577069146608315, 0.991765551601423, 1.89829438202247, 3.78251082024433, 5.79977216494845), avg_temp = c(16.0316901876571, 18.3219319089409, 17.4305069286691, 19.6999111947049, 18.0953880070785, 19.9364439125611, 15.8835964890026, 14.4286141669613, 15.8520719903777, 17.8671425490923, 16.9792535286348, 19.4983111172915, 18.0384627644668, 19.796581219498, 15.8923616798557, 14.3930096012531, 15.9462249963934,  18.0131168554757, 17.0146644246617, 19.3670299864879, 17.9620555512601, 19.9966781634639, 15.9588883573359, 14.3996170834378, 15.9102787695991, 17.9027418850032, 16.6426989587543, 19.3766862229857, 17.7782370211302, 19.9911596386168, 15.4336383745866, 14.4078720844153, 15.894660182529, 17.7701506997547, 16.5199154112426, 18.9558676499587, 17.8471091423835, 19.8014985569051, 15.7680670420329, 14.2370750045776, 14.8973653122079, 16.7578861254623, 16.0172205739373, 18.5551423442421, 17.7149749217095,  19.5071658581414, 15.4309343656536, 14.2014715330941, 15.3321192443371, 17.431807574597, 16.0510861331019, 17.5805371602376, 17.1988430109369, 19.3268852720455, 14.6497817119407, 14.2654214700063, 15.7534859397195, 17.3414096758347, 15.8644088745117, 17.6910490946571, 17.2494401363226, 19.6997255164699, 15.137482019152, 14.3955909729004, 15.6570347332564, 17.6080672569995, 15.7628102178159, 17.3501061742956, 17.3945586058549, 19.6723900415427, 14.9409176138944, 14.3039927202112, 15.2939747463573,  17.5678617249674, 15.6416156734277, 17.5087952361387, 17.540857042871, 19.5979144995191, 15.673808556731, 14.3753153392247, 16.0425170696143, 17.4133093886905, 15.6507201670588, 18.0531937029627, 17.6412752739826, 19.72914738925, 15.6248681115808, 14.2064579273092, 15.5793134126087, 17.1109770460082, 16.1793584239726, 18.0646989207519, 17.6148197809206, 19.7433430785177, 15.1988610282658, 14.2541516010578, 15.248302409898, 17.178797357865, 16.6500379143692, 18.2335877908084, 17.8113581964621, 19.8184388639398,  15.7196363848937, 14.2767914387218, 15.8123910992132, 17.1790603231023, 16.9620295138326, 18.590006396645, 18.0490843963623, 20.0932535064617, 16.4582798283275, 14.4041636751053, 16.3688073278072, 16.4052807274511, 17.343876319203, 19.1630856955051, 18.4148493790765, 20.299976194322, 16.3718331953156, 14.4724797074513, 16.3307339011646, 16.401790041123, 17.6226145170068, 19.5913128993587, 18.4194232483418, 20.4276151788949, 16.053676228693, 14.5162285099859, 16.3487099634338, 16.5845499682527, 17.5119909567519,  19.6658194174915, 18.5797102949749, 20.5213436422279, 14.9494875146121, 14.4916801568938, 17.3763293075562, 18.8124839826064, 18.1155957875552, 20.5523534040341, 18.9863680233112, 20.2543153991242, 15.3072674700603, 14.4353803103087, 16.7469552876998, 18.8632311047734, 18.1694983851407, 20.6087210666858, 18.8351857963118, 19.6952620882663, 15.4738927533864, 14.4828521996214, 16.0209554838098, 17.2570463307314, 17.534380493001, 19.6371749353609, 18.6765488419148, 19.9238736603665, 15.0897291594022,  14.5432929420471, 15.2783992807916, 16.8539676217472, 17.2031726410595, 19.0886267360606, 18.8249777717981, 20.1279337541112, 15.3480841190971, 14.440301252448, 15.7159928014456, 18.0787125337124, 17.3524328821428, 20.0888744604849, 18.6865335841586, 20.0968832655129, 15.2440366946192, 14.3961863768728, 15.8580124621121, 18.3873531296041, 17.4143823683709, 19.9601666363319, 18.5878530787444, 19.9652748415547, 15.4271978095726, 14.4166956228368, 15.9985944682902, 18.3746790468623, 17.6779030137632,  19.7467874468547, 18.2866756479935, 20.0260849490673, 15.6337777848435, 14.3993138480432)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -192L), groups = structure(list(hour = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L,  9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L,  22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L), month = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,  5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(     1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L,      102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L,      185L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -192L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: Your `structure` and code are corrupted with backslashes. I suggested an edit to fix all of that, please verify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to make this happen:

1. We can `rev`erse the formula in `sec_axis`;
2. I think we need not just a `coeff`icient, also an intercept;
3. Since the primary axis is inverted, we also need to invert the secondary data itself (so that the reversed-reversal is upright).

I'm going to suggest using `scales::rescale` to scale the `avg_temp` to the same range as `avg_depth`, and then invert it (`max(.) - .`). (I also suggest coloring the axis labels as well, to further disambiguate which axes apply to which line/data.)

```r
library(dplyr) # assuming based on the data, but this can easily be done without dplyr
dat2 <- dat %>%
  ungroup() %>% # important, as rescaling within each month/hour will skew things
  mutate(
    avg_temp_adj = scales::rescale(avg_temp, to = rev(range(avg_depth)))
  )

coefs <- c(
  diff(range(dat$avg_temp)) / diff(range(dat$avg_depth)),
  min(dat$avg_temp) - min(dat$avg_depth)
)

ggplot(dat2, aes(x = hour)) +
  facet_wrap(~ month) +
  geom_line(aes(y = avg_depth), color = "black") +
  geom_line(aes(y = avg_temp_adj), color = "red") +
  scale_y_continuous(
    trans = "reverse", name = "depth m",
    breaks = seq(0, 7.5, 1),
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~rev(.*coefs[1] + coefs[2]), name = "temp c", breaks = seq(14,22,1))
  ) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    axis.title.y = element_text(color = "black", size=13),
    axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "red", size=13),
    axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "red"))
```

[image: ggplot2 with two axes, one flipped]

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I really appreciate you and your help! That is exactly the solution I needed.

Comment: I do have another quick question. I have the same type of data for another year and the depth only ranged from 0-4 while the temperature range was the same, if I were to recreate this with the next years data, would the scaling work the same? I tried and it doesn't seem to want to scale the same

Comment: I assumed that you would control the target range by `range(avg_depth)`, but you can control that arbitrarily. Everywhere you see that (twice in my code), you can hard-code `c(0.1, 7.2)` for this and the next year's data so that the axes will be approximately the same. However ... depending on your `avg_temp` data (in the other data), you may also wish to control `range(avg_temp)` as well, which shows in one place in my code *but also* in an implicit place, `scales::rescale(..., from=)` also will need to be adjusted.

Comment: In either case, I suggest you be rather explicit in your range control and do it consistently: one way of "lying" in plots is to change the scale between plots of similar data, so that there appears to be significance where it may not exist. Many are against dual-axis plots like this for that reason, though I try to explicitly manage that by changing the color of the second axis labels (as well as the color of the axis name).